# In Leaflet for R, can column variables be used to vary size of labelOption size, colour, etc.?

Tags: r, openstreetmap, r-leaflet

I am trying to create a high-quality map of a small part of the UK, without any distortions caused by the use of projections, and with the addition of markers consisting of text and symbols. Ultimately the goal is to write out a png or pdf file. An earlier, related question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57124407/plotting-sea-areas-using-osmplotr-and-openstreetmap-in-r).

Having not used R in anger for several years, I have been wading through a morass of packages trying to find something suitable. Leaflet for R is promising, but although I can create a decent-looking map, add markers, and vary the colour of markers and so on using columns from a data frame, I have not been able to vary the size, colour, and text offsets used in the `labelOptions`  argument.

[image: Piccadilly with markers using Leaflet for R]

The following reproducible example shows what I can achieve, and also where I am not succeeding. I would like the size of text label to vary according to the `df.data$textsizes` column. Given that the `style` argument takes a list of value pairs, that would seem difficult, and nothing has worked so far.

If am hoping that somebody can either suggest either a way to bend the wily `labelOptions` to my will, or a completely different approach to try.

```
require(leaflet)
require(magrittr)

df.entrynames <- c("Entry 1: Some text","Entry 2: More text")
df.lat <- c(51.509898,51.510736)
df.lon <- c(-0.1345093,-0.135190)
df.colors <-c("Blue","Red")
df.sizes <-c(36,12)
df.data <- data.frame(entrynames=df.entrynames,lat=df.lat,lon=df.lon,colors=df.colors,textsizes=df.sizes)
df.data$entrynames <- as.character(df.data$entrynames)
df.data$colors <- as.character(df.data$colors)
df.data$textsizes <- paste(df.data$textsizes,"px",sep="")

leaflet() %>% setView(lng = -0.134509, lat = 51.509898, zoom = 17) %>% addTiles() %>%
       addCircleMarkers(data = df.data,
              lat = ~lat, lng = ~lon,
              label = df.data$entrynames,
              color = df.data$colors,
              labelOptions = labelOptions(noHide = TRUE,
                                          style = list(
                                                        "color" = "gray30",
                                                        "font-family" = "serif",
                                                        "font-style" = "italic",
                                                        "box-shadow" = "3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.25)",
                                                        "font-size" = "14px",
                                                        "border-color" = "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)"
                                           ),
                                          textOnly = FALSE,
                                          offset=c(0,0)))
```

Comment: `labeloptions(textsize=~textsizes,...)`  ?

Comment: Thanks. That was my first thought, but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  df.entrynames <- c("Entry 1: Some text","Entry 2: More text")
  df.lat <- c(51.509898,51.510736)
  df.lon <- c(-0.1345093,-0.135190)
  df.colors <-c("Blue","Red")
  df.sizes <-c(36,2)
  df.data <- data.frame(entrynames=df.entrynames,lat=df.lat,lon=df.lon,colors=df.colors,textsizes=df.sizes)
  df.data$entrynames <- as.character(df.data$entrynames)
  df.data$colors <- as.character(df.data$colors)
  df.data$textsizes <- paste(df.data$textsizes,"px",sep="")
  #Add a vector to split the data by     
  df.data$place<-seq(1:nrow(df.data))


  library(purrr)    

#split the data
  ob_place <- df.data %>% 
    split(., .$place)
#make a map
  m <- leaflet() %>% 
    addTiles() 

#Add layers
  names(ob_place) %>%
    purrr::walk(function(df.data) {
      m<<-m %>% #seems like there's supposed to be two carrots here, i had problems without one
        addCircleMarkers(data=ob_place[[df.data]],fillColor=~colors,
                         fillOpacity = 0.6,
                         weight=1,
                         radius=13,
                         color="white",
                         opacity = .6,
                         lng=~lon, lat=~lat,
                         group = "Show All",
                         label = ~entrynames,
                         labelOptions = labelOptions(noHide = T,
                                                     #direction = ~MyDirection, #https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/popups.html
                                                     textsize = ~textsizes,
                                                     #opacity=~opacity,
                                                     style = list(
                                                       "color"="black",
                                                       "font-family" ="sans-serif",
                                                       "box-shadow" = "3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.25)",
                                                       #"font-size" = "12px",
                                                       "border-color" = "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)"
                                                     )))

    })
m
```

[image]

Similar to setting the [direction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55159622/r-leaflet-label-set-direction) of labels

Comment: Thanks, not as familiar with the tidyverse as I (apparently) should be, so will have to do a little study and respond in a day or two.